# How does one best translate 老在 into english

Tags: translation

I couldn't  find any translation in my dictionaries. Though. In context it seems to mean 'always'?! 
这孩子老在班上捣蛋。
Is this correct.

Cheers

Comment: iciba： 老 <副> long ； always ； very 
在班上捣蛋 To act up in class

Answer (score 4):

老在 is not a word. It's an adverb followed by a preposition.

老 means always or constantly.

在 is just a preposition, here it would be 'on' to go with 班上(the class)

So it's: This kid always create troubles on the class.

Comment: I think I got i got it, thanks for providing me with the terminology

Comment: it is all in the dictionaries, to determine proper separation into words you could first use iciba 翻译

Answer (score 2):

老 is an adjective, means old.

It then be used as an adverb, long time, always, since old means long time.

For example, 这孩子老捣蛋。商店里老有人偷钱包。

在班上 is a adverb phrase means location, where to happen.